# Convert from list to numeric

Tags: r, list, double, coerce

I am tying to coerce from list form to numeric form. If it is of use, the list is originally drawn from a factor (and is 1x33 rows).

My list is defined by:

```
tmpseqsf[[1]]
```

which provides:

```
       TradeValue
1    72914431
2       25325
3       20139
4       ...
```

So based on other advice (Stackoverflow, etc) I use:

```
tmpx <-as.numeric(tmpseqsf[[1]])
```

but I get the error:

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

And just confirming nothing has happened:

```
is.numeric(tmpseqsf[[1]])
[1] FALSE
```

Is there something I am completely missing?

Comment: try `as.numeric(unlist(tmpseqsf[[1]]))`

Comment: Thanks ahly - certainly converted to numeric form but the values changed from say 72914431 to 31

Comment: If the values are of type factor, then you should convert them by `as.numeric(as.character(unlist(tmpseqsf[[1]])))`

Comment: Works - greatly appreciate your help here!.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the values are of type factor, then you should convert them by `as.numeric(as.character(unlist(tmpseqsf[[1]])))`